# How do i Quickly Process a csproj file in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm making a Pre-Compiler meaning it will read a load of files and process a few custom preprocessor directives. but no matter how much I look online I can't find a working processor for the .csproj file. I can read them and extract data. but I can't process them to extract state with Configuration and platform parameters.

what I mean is, if I have a csproj that adds a few preprocessor directives if on the DEBUG build and others on the RELEASE build, I want to be able to process the file so that when I build of DEBUG I correctly get all then defined Preprocessors and likewise for the RELEASE build.

I'm going to be processing dotnet core projects to be specific.

Comment: So you want to identify the compiler directives and build configurations during pre-build phase?

Comment: @TroyPalacino, Basically yes, I want to get the file state after processing all conditions using the Platform and Configuration.

this includes stuff like OutputPath, AllowUnsafe, BuildTargets and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the file state after processing all conditions using the
>   Platform and Configuration. this includes stuff like OutputPath,
>   AllowUnsafe, BuildTargets and such.

The c# compiler, unlike the c++ compiler, does not have specific **precompiled** instruction item elements destined for the compiler like `PreprocessorDefinitions`.

As a suggestion, you can try to add a custom [target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) in `xxxx.csproj` file to execute [some msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) to do some preprocessing. And you want to do all of these after `pre-build` target, you can just set `AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild"` to this custom target which means it runs after `PrepareForBuild` target.

**Suggesstion**

Just like this:

```
<Target Name="CustomPreprocessor" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">

<Message Importance="high" Text="$(OutputPath)--$(AllowUnsafeBlocks)--$(PrepareForBuildDependsOn)" ></Message>

 ........//other msbuild task

 </Target>
```

**1)**  If you want to use the **configuration** as a condition and execute different pre-instructions according to `Debug` or `Release`, you can use [MSBuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019).
If you want to use `Debug`, you can refer to this:

```
<Target Name="CustomPreprocessor" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
```

At the same time, if you also want to add **palform** as a parallel condition, please try this:

```
 <Target Name="CustomPreprocessor" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' and '$(Platform)' =='Any CPU' ">
```

**2)** Since `outputpath` and `AllowUnsafe` are MSBuild properties, you can use `$(outputpath)` and `$(AllowUnsafeBlocks)` to get their values while you can use `@(...)` to get values of [MSBuild items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019).

**3)** Basically, to execute a preinstruction in target, you can do it with a task, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference?view=vs-2019) to add any task as you want to do any operation.

Comment: If l misunderstand your issue, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't quite understand what I want to do, I'm creating a preprocessor to ingest c# files and process custom preprocessor directives, what I want to do is add support for MSBuild configs meaning it will read a .csproj file and extract what state the build is when parsing configuration and platform. if I can execute a program and parse all the MSBuild directives by using a target then this would help. can I do that from within a target?

Comment: If you want to create a custom preprocessor  under c# compiler `csc.exe` or a just a new compiler , I think you could extend MSBuild by coding. You can create a new  console projectctcode, inheritance [Microsoft.Build.Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.csc?view=netframework-4.8) and [Microsoft.Build.Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework?view=netframework-4.8) by nuget and then create a custom build.exe engine to build your project.

Comment: Besides, since codes of MSBuild is open-source. You can refer to it([github link](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild)) and then modify as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out, and yea my plan is to wrap around the Build engine when using VS, that way if MSBuild gets updated my code will still work with any changes to the builder/compiler.